# Creating my own interrupt service routine

Tags: assembly, x86-16

how can I create my own Interrupt Service Routine(ISR) ?
I cant understand the concept of interrupt vector table , I am trying to write an assembly 8086 code to do  a simple operation when I call a interrupt that I previously defined.

For example  if I want to define INT70 , for address CS:IP will be
CS=70 × 4 +2
IP=70×4
then what should I do ?

Comment: Write your handler then put the address into the table at the location you indicated. You can start out with something like `add ax, bx; iret` to create a service to add numbers or similar.

Comment: Try reading this: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2602.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should serve as a template for it:

```
Set_ISR_Vector:
push ds

mov ax, seg ISR_Handler
mov ds,ax

mov dx, offset ISR_Handler
mov ax, 2570h  ;mov ah, 25h and mov al,70h
int 21h 

pop ds
ret

ISR_Handler:
add ax,bx
iret
```

Comment: @AnasNss11 Installed new interrupt handler should be properly chained with whichever old handler might exist for the same interrupt number. Look at [TSR clock](https://euroassembler.eu/prodos16/tsrclock.htm) example.